# Any way to automatically calculate Annular regions of nerve cells in ImageJ?

Tags: analysis, imagej, roi, particles

I'm trying to do a particle analysis of cross section of nerve cells. In essence, each nerve fiber has an outer and inner radius and I want to calculate the annular region. It's fairly simple to convert the image to a binary one, and then analyze particles, but it only gives the area of the outer region (inner region included). I want to somehow automate finding the outer region (marked by the outer edge of the black band) area less the inner region (marked off by the inner edges of the black band). Picture is related to what I'm talking about (the image is a sample and has already been converted to binary).

[[image: Nerve cell cross sections converted to binary in ImageJ]]

Answer (score 0):

You should first invert the image, the white patterns will be what you want to analyze. Then, you apply a connected component labeling in order to separate the patterns, and then you can analyze them one by one.

Unfortunately, I don't think that the connected component labeling and separation exists in ImageJ, but you can take a look to the union-find algorithm, it's pretty simple. Here is a [java code](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d480842/general-developpement/algorithme-mathematiques/contribuez/java-etiquettage-composantes-connexes-union-find/).